# breadcrumbs not displaying correctly for views

Tags: breadcrumbs, taxonomy-terms

I'm pretty new to the world of drupal so I'm hoping this will be a quick fix.

Anyhow here's the situation:
my breadcrumbs work correctly when hitting a node for example when i go to "contact" it prints out home > contact.  Now I have a view and when I go there things look ok. I go to events and it prints out home > events > view all. When I go to a subview like "tech events" however it spits out home > events > events > view all.

The code below is what is currently in place so I was wondering how to alter it to handle views or if anyone could point me to a good solution.

thank you

my code:

```
function custom_breadcrumb($variables) {
  $currentTitle = "";
  $trail = menu_get_active_trail();
  $currentNode = array_pop($trail);
  if( $currentNode ){
    $currentTitle = $currentNode['title'];
  }

  $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];
  if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {

    $output = '<ul class="breadcrumb"><li>';
    $output .= implode('</li><li class="breadcrumb-seperator"><!--&raquo;--></li><li class="breadcrumb-seperator-border"></li><li>', $breadcrumb);

    if( $currentTitle ){
      $output .= '</li><li class="breadcrumb-seperator"><!--&raquo;--></li><li class="breadcrumb-seperator-border"></li><li class="active">';
      $output .= $currentTitle;
    }
    $output .= '</li></ul>';

    return $output;
  }
}
```

any help would be awesome guys. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so it still needs some work to be a little more generic but this basically handles the case. It checks to make sure that the content-type is not a node we check to see if there's an additional argument and append that to the breadcrumbs. if it is a node we just print out hte breadcrumb trail checking to make sure that we don't repeat things. If you use a page jump, fragments, or redirects you might get a repeat, i.e. home > stories > stories.  So here it is.

```
function custom_breadcrumb($variables) {
  $currentTitle = "";
  $trail = menu_get_active_trail();
  $currentNode = array_pop($trail);
  if( $currentNode ){
    $currentTitle = $currentNode['title'];
  }

  $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];
  if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
    $lastCrumb = NULL;

    $output = '<h2 class="element-invisible">' . t('You are here') . '</h2>';

    $output .= '<ul class="breadcrumb"><li>';

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($breadcrumb); $i++) {
    $curCrumb = strip_tags($breadcrumb[$i]);
    if ($i == 0) {
      $output .= $breadcrumb[$i];
      $lastCrumb = strip_tags($breadcrumb[$i]);
    } elseif (strpos($breadcrumb[$i], $lastCrumb) === false) {
      $output .= '</li><li class="breadcrumb-seperator" data-test="testing"><!--&raquo;--></li><li class="breadcrumb-seperator-border"></li><li>' . $breadcrumb[$i];
      $lastCrumb = strip_tags($breadcrumb[$i]);
    }
  }

  if (arg(0) != 'node' ) {
    $output .= '</li><li class="breadcrumb-seperator"><!--&raquo;--></li><li class="breadcrumb-seperator-border"></li><li class="active">';
    $output .= arg(1);
  } elseif( $currentTitle ){
    $output .= '</li><li class="breadcrumb-seperator"><!--&raquo;--></li><li class="breadcrumb-seperator-border"></li><li class="active">';
    $output .= $currentTitle;
  }
  $output .= '</li></ul>';

  return $output;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'd probably skip all the custom stuff and just use [Path Breadcrumbs](https://drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs)

> This module is a solution for all problems with the breadcrumbs on
>   your site!
>
> Path Breadcrumbs module helps you to create breadcrumbs for **any page**
>   with **any selection rules** and load **any entity** from the URL!

They're also exportable, so if you want them in code you can either export them and implement the default hook, or use [Features](http://www.drupal.org/project/features).